# Is colorring each document and word as monochromatic as possible the goal of LDA in specific or all topic models in general?

Tags: topic-model, lda

In the video [Training Latent Dirichlet Allocation: Gibbs Sampling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaM1uiCpj_E&t=452s), the Goal section at 7:32, the video says that:

> Goal: Color each word with blue, green, red
>
> 1. Each article is as monochromatic as possible
> 2. Each word is as monochromatic as possible

[image: 1]

I wonder if this is correct for LDA only, or for all topic models in general?